# Why check for Match.Success

Tags: c#, regex

In a code sample I saw a `foreach` loop going over the matches of a `regex`. Inside the loop there was a check for `match.Success`. But wouldn't all these matches be a success? Otherwise they wouldn't be matches, would they?

Am I wrong to think that (in this situation) the check is redundant?

```
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var matches = regex.Matches(input);
var list = new List<string>();
foreach (Match m in matches) {
    if (m.Success) {
        list.Add(m.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to include the code you are describing.

Comment: Need to see the code. `Match()`, `Matches()` and `MatchNext()` all work differently - we need to know what they're using to answer this.

Comment: How on earth is this off-topic? I'm trying to understand how to process Regex matches correctly.

Comment: @fwend I think it was closed as unanswerable because you hadn't included key context that was required to give a sensible answer; you're now included that, so: great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are looping on the return value from `Regex.Matches`, then yes: the check is redundant. `Matches()` uses the same object that `Match()` uses, and with `Match()` it isn't known whether you have a match or not - hence the `.Success` property to tets that. With `Matches()`, you *only get* successes, but: the object model is still the same.

You don't need to check `.Success` when using `Matches()`

Answer (score 4):

The [Regex.Match() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) and related [Match.NextMatch() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch(v=vs.110).aspx) always returns a [Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx) object instance. However, you can only determine if the regular expression matched the input text by checking the [Match.Success property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.success(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Gets a value indicating whether the match is successful.

However, as Marc pointed out it is also possible to use the [Matches() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx) to get an entire collection of (only true) Match objects at once, in which case checking the property would be redundant.

So, yes in the code snippet you (finally) provided the `Success` check is unnecessary.

Comment: But the mention of a loop suggests that they're using `Regex.Matches`, in which case all should be positive matches...

Comment: Not necessarily, they could be using `match = match.NextMatch()` in a loop in which case you need to check success on each iteration. See the code snippet [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: fair point; ultimately, then, it comes down to the context - that OP didn't include (edit: they have now)